# ISP throttling only windows devices upload speed

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, internet, isp

Hey guys so recently i have been facing upload speed issues with windows 10, my internet speed is 8mbps up/down, my upload speed seems to be throttled by ISP but only on windows devices. when i live boot into linux with the same machine i get the full 8mbps speeds, also on android,ios and smart tv i get full speeds. but on windows pc the upload is capped at 0.7mbps-1.2mbps. i have tried with 5 different laptops/desktop all with ethernet and wifi, i have also reset all the routers and it's still the same. so now i came to the conclusion that my ISP is throttling windows devices. QUESTION: can ISP really cap only windows devices? and is there anyway i can trick the ISP to think  that i'm using a linux device so i can bypass the throttling? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=1` on Linux, does it become very slow too?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Are you sure you're not confusing MBps with Mbps?

Answer (score 1):

It is **extremely unlikely** your ISP is throttling your Windows devices as this would be very hard to do, and would achieve very little at significant cost.

Its more likely your Windows network stack is behaving differently to your Linux (and android uses linux) one - the million dollar question is "how".  First thing I wpuld try is reducing the mtu of the windows network card. Try 1476, if that works, try incrrasing in 8 byte increments until it goes slowly.

Comment: tried that yesterday didnt work. i can let you RDP to my PC and help me diagnose. and isp has a reputation of throttling and censorship. Huawei manages all their network therefore they have the capablities required, all windows devices in my network are behaving this way not just one pc. when i live boot to linux on the same devices the speed will be back to normal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do sites like youtube load fast? (I ask because they use an extension of https - QUIC - which runs iver udp)

Comment: Yes download is all good. Besides they have a cache server attached to the ISP. My only problem is UPLOAD